# ConverterNotFoundException marshall CsvDataFormat with Spring boot

Tags: csv, spring-boot, apache-camel, marshalling

I try to marshall a `List<List<String>>` to CSV with a route like:

```
from("direct:ListToCsv").marshal(csvDataFormat_list).convertBodyTo(String.class).to("mock:ListToCsv");
```

In `CsvMarshaller.getRecordValues`, there's a "convert to Map" called there that doesn't have the same behavior if camel Spring boot is used (maybe just in camel spring, don't know).

If SpringTypeConverter is enabled (wich is automatic in spring boot) the method "convertTo" throw an ConverterNotFoundException and the route stop there.

Before spring-boot (or if I remove it), the conversion to map in the CsvMarshaller return null and the conversion is executed as list and it works.

So, question... I think it's a bug or do I miss something with the use of Spring for fallback type converter (I didn't use it before)?

Thanks!

**[UPDATE]**

It seems to be fixed in the next version of camel-csv (2.16.X)